# Java Security Option to prevent Thread.sleep(...) invocation

Tags: java, multithreading, security, wait, api-design

Is there a way (e.g., via Java security policy) to prohibit a "codebase" from directly invoking Thread.sleep(...)?

The current Oracle listing http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html does not seem to indicate anything for this...

Comment: Why is calling `sleep()` a security issue?

Comment: Well, pretty much just a way to ensure client code doesn't slow itself down. Essentially, I have an API that client Java code integrates with, and this API already handles any necessary "waits" (all such cases). I just want to prevent clients from doing that...

Comment: The Java API makes no mention of a SecurityException for Thread.sleep(), not does the API mention that a security manager is called.  So I'm guessing "no, there's no way you can use a standard mechanism like a security manager" for this.

Comment: What about all the other potentially blocking calls?

Comment: Just a random idea. Use reflection to make `Thread.sleep()` private?

Comment: What about a `for` loop that does nothing but delay?  That's a popular way of slowing things down.

Comment: How about forcing the user to specify a timeout/wait condition as part of the API? E.g. Like the Future interface's get(long timeout, TimeUnit). Or sculpt the API around using callbacks for results, forcing the user to handle them asynchronously (yes there are some ways around this still). Some pseudo-code of how the API is used, especially around how data is returned to the user, might help with giving you feedback.

Comment: You could create a custom classloader that parses bytecode to detect calls to Thread.sleep() or even wait loops, but there will almost always be away around it. Probably not worth the effort.